# Why does returning const reference from a lambda result in a temporary?

Tags: c++, lambda, reference, c++14, constants

I have a situation where I have a member returning a `const&`, and then this result is being forwarded within a lambda, which has the same return type.

MSVC2017 identifies this situation as risky, and issues a warning: `returning address of local variable or temporary`. Empirical testing with clang and other compilers shows this is true across the board. What I do not understand, is why this is different than several method calls which all return the same type.

For example, this works perfectly:

```
class A {
public:
    const std::string& name() const { return m_name; }
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

class B {
public:
    const std::string& name() const { return m_a.name(); }
private:
    A m_a;
};

//...
B b;
std::cout << b.name();
```

Works as expected, no warnings/errors at compile or runtime.

But with a lambda, it doesn't:

```
class A {
public:
    const std::string& name() const { return m_name; }
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

//...
using Getter = std::function< const std::string&() >;
A a;
Getter g = [&a] { return a.name(); };
std::cout << g();
```

results in a crash, or at least printing corrupted memory

Can someone point me to some info about why this does not work? I would generally expect it to work the same...

Comment: Note that in [tag:C++17] I'd replace `std::string const&` with `std::string_view` and magically your code works properly with zero runtime cost and your intended semantics.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: you only *sometimes* need `std::function` (e.g. to wrap and store multiple lambdas in the same container).  The rest of the time, it's perfectly fine (and slightly more performant) to just have `auto g = `.

Comment: @Rakete1111 No, because the lambda will return a *copy of the view* not a *copy of the string*, and everything works like rainbows and unicorns.

Comment: @Yakk Ah, so you want to replace *every* use of `const std::string&`. :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes, as a general philosophical position, every `const std::string&` should be replaced with `std::string_view`.  But also in the OP's question, where it fixes the bug as a side effect.

Comment: we are not using C++17 yet. Also please keep in mind this is a distilled example. We are using the lambda for other reasons

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The return type of your lambda is *not* a reference. This is the cause of all your problems.

Your lambda returns a copy of the name. You are storing this lambda in a `std::function` returning a `const std::string&`, which means that effectively, you will return a reference to that copy which will get destroyed as soon as `std::function`'s call operator returns!<sup>1</sup>

Naturally, the fix is to change the return type of the lambda:

```
Getter g = [&a]() -> const std::string& { return a.name(); };

// or
Getter g = [&a]() -> auto& { return a.name(); };
// or if you are feeling fancy :P
Getter g = [&a]() -> decltype(auto) { return a.name(); };
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: To expand a bit on this, you can imagine `std::function`'s implementation as something like this (only the relevant parts are shown and massively simplified):

```
template<typename R, typename... Ts>
struct function<R(Ts...)> {
  R operator()(Ts... Args) const {
    return callInternalFunctionObject(Args...); // here: copy will get destructed
  }
};
// R=const std::string&, and Ts is empty
```

Comment: So `[&a]() -> decltype(auto) { return a.name(); }` returns a reference but not `[&a]() { return a.name(); }`? I would have expected that the default when no return type is specified would be `decltype(auto)`

Comment: @agbinfo Ah no, it's `auto` :)

Comment: The other way of making it work is with `auto &` as the return type -- the problem being that `auto` never infers a reference unless you explicitly tell it to (with either the extra `&` or with `decltype`)